# Fired a event when scroll to down for dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I want to fired a event when dropdown is scrolled to down.
My **.ts** look like this

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
     onWindowScroll(): void {
            let position = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
            let maximum = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
            if(position >= maximum )   {
                console.log(document.body.className);
            }
      }
```

but it works for whole page not for dropdown
 My **html** looks like this

```
<ng-select #postCodeDD [items]="postCodes" bindLabel="displayName"
                                                bindValue="id" class="width-percent-100 scroll-event-fordropdown" name="CodeCode"
                                                placeholder="select postcode" appendTo="body"
                                                (change)="CodeChange($event)" [virtualScroll]="true"
                                                [selectOnTab]="true" [(ngModel)]="patientEntry.postCodeId">
                                            </ng-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(scrollToEnd)` event provided by the ng-select. For use that needs to enable virtual scroll like this `[virtualScroll] = 'true'`. 
Refer this: https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select

Comment: @kushanSammera, but it fired event only for one time, did I mess anything.

Comment: @kushanSammera, i messed with my code its working fine. Thanx for your time

Comment: @kabindhital Great.

Comment: @kabindhital Could you please tell me what did you messed up? I am also facing the same issue, the event is fired only once.

Comment: @Shivam what I did actually I forgot, however as per my knowledge I change (change) event to (ngOnChange).